# Jhipster/spring boot static resources pdf file not bundled when running via Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I have created jhipster monolithic application (signupApp) "jhipsterVersion": "5.2.0", Client - **Angular**

Here is my **.yo-rc.json**

```
{
   "generator-jhipster": {
"promptValues": {
  "packageName": "com.labkit.sci.signup",
  "nativeLanguage": "en"
},
"jhipsterVersion": "5.2.0",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"baseName": "signupApp",
"packageName": "com.labkit.sci.signup",
"packageFolder": "com/labkit/sci/signup",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"cacheProvider": "no",
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "gradle",
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"jwtSecretKey": "0090063692719408ae6b537297eb0489f240d788",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "yarn",
"testFrameworks": [],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
  "en",
  "es"
]
  }
  }
```

I have added a **"doc"** directory under **\src\main\webapp\content\doc** with a pdf file

then added an entry in **webpack.common.js**

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
              .
              ..
              .
        { from: './src/main/webapp/content/doc/agreement-gdpr.pdf', to: 'content/doc/agreement-gdpr.pdf' },
              .
              .
              .

    ])
```

The pdf got packed inside the war when i execute manually "**gradlew bootWar -Pprod**"

however when the war generated using cli (jenkins)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
  stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm
}

stage('check java') {
    sh "java -version"
}

stage('clean') {
    sh "chmod +x gradlew"
    sh "./gradlew clean --no-daemon"
}

stage('install tools') {
    sh "./gradlew yarn_install -PnodeInstall --no-daemon"
}

stage('packaging') {
try {
    sh "./gradlew bootWar -x test -Pprod -PnodeInstall --no-daemon"
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/build/libs/*.war', fingerprint: true
    } catch (e) {
     // If there was an exception thrown, the build failed
       currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
     throw e
    } finally {
       // Success or failure, always send notifications
      //    notifyBuild(currentBuild.result)
    }
    }

   }
```

In the content directory we will have only the css ,png, fonts . But missing **doc** directory ,

The size of the war file also reduced when compared to local war build.

[image]

Comment: What client framework are you using?  I couldn't reproduce locally using the commands from your question.

Comment: @JonRuddell updated the .yo-rc.json